# How to use the front camera with Tango?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, 2.1-eclair, front-camera

Like lots of us, I guess, I discovered Tango today (one the greatest app !)
As I own a Galaxy S, I wonder if we can use the front camera while talking.
I know we can do that using the builtin visiocall app.

Does anybody know the hack ?

http://www.appbrain.com/app/tango-video-calls/com.sgiggle.production

Thanks.

Comment: Nobody tried this out ?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a reason you can't use the front-facing camera. It seems that's what the app is designed for. It even says [here](http://www.androidtapp.com/tango-video-calls/) that you don't need a front-facing camera.

Why you think you need a "hack?" Looks like you just need another person with the Tango app... http://tango.me/product/how_tango.php. Maybe I misunderstood your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Recent Changes list for v1.4.4857 (released around 11/11/10) states:

> - We added support for front facing cameras on Samsung devices
> - We fixed an issue that was causing some HTC EVOs to reboot when launching
>     Tango

So it looks like they needed to change something specific in their software to let you use the front facing camera, and they've done that now!